# Find consecutive empty cells in Matrix field

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to build a seat reservation system for a small cultural venue. I will be using a matrix field mimicing all the seats (rows for seat rows, colums for seat numbers). If someone makes a reservation for 3 seats, I would like to go through the Matrix field (in the template, not in de CP) and find 3 consecutive empty fields.
Would this be possible purely with EE code? Or should I dive into php, and if so, what would be the best solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely sounds like something that will involve some PHP along with some SQL queries to loop through the result set. The cleanest way would be to place it in an [extension](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html) which gets called at the time of making a reservation. I'm not sure if you're using an ecommerce addon or not so can't provide a specific hook but each cart will no doubt have a [hook](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/) which you can use to latch on to at that point in the process to execute your extension and make the query.